# Is it viable to extend hose of a vacuum cleaner?

Tags: vacuum

It may be a dumb question. I have always been dreaming a stationary vacuum cleaner which is placed geometrically in the middle of a flat, has a very long hose (depends on the area of the flat, say 15 meters for 110 square-meters flat), reaches every corner of the flat, has every single kit for any type of surface and a powerful motor.

I am not very good at physics but I know that increasing hose causes lower suction due to friction. However, I wonder what are the chances to make this real?

Comment: Whole-house vacuum systems are a thing, with the blower in the basement and various outlets around the house to plug the hose into where needed.

Comment: you will also find that the built-in vacuum systems Jon Custer cites use hoses of larger diameter than those in small portable vacuums. furthermore, since the vacuum turbine and motor are fixed in position, you can install a stronger (heavier) motor to pull more air through the hoses. these two things will compensate for the extra hose length required in this scheme.